# Remove Duplicates From List<T> Based on Property Selected By Lambda

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I've a `List<User>` which have several keys. I have several scenarios. In some cases I want to remove duplicates based on Key1 and in other based on Key2. Both properties on the User object.

I thought this would be as simple as to give the Distinct function a generic IEqualityComparer like this:

```
public class AwesomeEqualityComparerOfDoom<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly Func<T, object> compiledFunction;

    public AwesomeEqualityComparerOfDoom(Func<T, object > propertyFunction)
    {
        compiledFunction = propertyFunction;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        object key1 = compiledFunction(x);
        object key2 = compiledFunction(y);
        return key1.Equals(key2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

When I test this class manually by creating an instance of it, and giving it two users with the same key, then it works. However, when I pass it off to the Distinct function no users are removed as being duplicates.

I also tried making the IEquality class be defined as `AwesomeEqualityComparerOfDoom<T,TT>`, so it knew what kind of value it would be calling Equals on but to no avail.

Comment: What happens if `key1` is `null`? Call `Equals(key1, key2)`

Comment: Please add your code that uses `.Distinct`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not using the `compiledFunction` in your `GetHashCode` implementation - you're just using the hash code of the item itself. You want something like:

```
public int GetHashCode(T obj)
{
    return compiledFunction(obj).GetHashCode();
}
```

However:

- You should consider making your class generic in the projected type as well, taking (say) `Func<TElement, TKey>` instead of just `Func<T, object>`
- You should consider using `EqualityComparer<TKey>` to handle null keys.

I have classes which help with this already in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) with helper methods so you can do things like this:

```
var comparer = ProjectionEqualityComparer<User>.Create(x => x.Name);
```

The key type is then inferred from the lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

`Distinct()` is a LINQ method that returns a new sequence without any duplicates.
It doesn't modify the original list.